# SSRS Multiple Column

Tags: ssrs-tablix

I am new to this SSRS. 
I have a record like this:

```
Table         Denomination  ResultType Quantity
```

---

```
A1             1.00           FC          5
A1             1.00           FR          10
A1             2.00           FC          21
A1             2.00           FR          23
A1             5.00           FC          11
A1             5.00           FR          16
A2             1.00           FC          15
A2             1.00           FR          20
A2             2.00           FC          25
A2             2.00           FR          26
A2             5.00           FC          10
A2             5.00           FR          17
```

I am only able to do 1 part using matrix. I'd tried using pivot too but due to the denomination is a dynamic field.

```
                   FC 
Denomination  1.00 2.00 5.00 
------------  ---- ---- ----   
  A1            5   21   11    
  A2            15  25   10
```

I want to populate something like this using tablix instead.

```
                  FC         |  FR
Denomination  1.00 2.00 5.00 | 1.00 2.00 5.00
------------  ---- ---- ----   ---- ---- ----
  A1            5   21   11     10   23   16
  A2            15  25   10     20   26   17
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you have control over your query to get the data ?

Comment: I have control to query the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a little late to help you but...

You should be able to do this be creating a matrix (tablix in BIDS 2005) with **Table**(? - the field with your A1, A2 data) as the **Row Group** and **Denomination** as the **Column Group**.

Then in the **Column Groups**, click on the **Denomination** group down arrow and Add Group->Parent Group and Group By **ResultType**. This will add the extra layer to the columns by **FC** and **FR** in your last example.